# Java lanterna Terminal put in java.properties file?

Tags: java, maze, lanterna

I'm quite new to programming (had it for a Semester now) and I'm supposed to use the Lanterna Libary (in my final project) to make a terminal in which I can run later a very simple Maze game with walls and static and dynamic "enemies" as well as some key objects which the player has to pick up. Sadly I have no clue what so ever how this would work. I put already around 10h in researching the matter but the only thing it brought me was frustration.

I found a tutorial on youtube where **javax.swing** is used to just make a **Konsole.add(new map())** phrase which is getting the map from a class which reads the whole thing into java from a **.txt**. I was hoping to do something like that but as said I have to just the **lanterna terminal** and read the map in from a **java.properties file**.

Is it possible to do that ? Or do I have to use a totally different Approach?
I looked on the website from lanterna and read throw it a few times but couldn't get really anything out of it that helped me. I also checked any post which included lanterna in it on this website but it just furthered my knowledge just a tiny bit. 
Any kind of tip or suggestion even if it is just a link to another article would help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all you have to initialize the lanterna console, this will bring up a new swing window which represents your lanterna console.

## Lanterna

You can use something like this:

```
//Init Lanterna terminal
Terminal terminal = TerminalFacade.createTerminal();
//Will bring up the terminal window
terminal.enterPrivateMode();
//Optional: you can hide the cursor so it wont blink
terminal.setCursorVisible(false);
```

so now you can use the methods `terminal.moveCursor(x, y)` and `terminal.putCharacter(char);` to print out your map.
And when you terminated your program you should call

```
terminal.exitPrivateMode();
```

## Properties file

So the first thing you have to is read the properties file in.

```
String filename = ""; //Filename or filepath to your .properties file
Properties properties = new Properties();
try {
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
    properties.load(inputStream);
    inputStream.close();
} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To retrieve data from the `Properties` object you can use the methods `properties.propertyNames()` and `properties.getProperty("PropertyName")`

```
Enumeration<?> propertyNames = properties.propertyNames();
while (propertyNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String name = (String) propertyNames.nextElement();
    String value = properties.getProperty(name);
    System.out.println("Name: "+name+"\tValue: "+value);
}
```

this prints out every entry from the `.properties` file. You now have the process the key-value pairs and probably store them in an array or collection. Then you can write a method to print them out to your Lanterna console and you can easily update them or save them back to a `.properties` file. Hope this helped a little bit :)

Comment: Thank you, this helps quite a bit! Would have given you a +1 but I don't have to min requierment of 15 rep points haha. Also I saw on a Q&A pages that another student just went:
**SwingTerminal terminal = TerminalFacade.createSwingTerminal();**
        **terminal.getJFrame().setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);**

basicly using JFrame over that. I think I'll go with that to :)
Thx again!

Comment: @Newbielvl.1 No problem, had to write the code anyway (; Yea you can surely use the `JFrame` way as well I don't think it's that different. The more annoying part is using `terminal.putCharacter()` and `terminal.moveCursor()` you just have to play around a bit with them to figure out how they work. Btw. You can accept the answer if it solved your problem but maybe you want to wait for other answers :)